# can we use brackets in when statement in yang model. And how to use "and" and "or" operators in it

Tags: yang

This leaf should be available only if we disable l3 access and the traffic type or types should be single vlan.

```
leaf VLAN-normalization 
{
    type enumeration 
{
        enum "Normalize to Dot1q tag";
        enum "Normalize to QinQ tags";
        enum "Normalize to VLAN none";
        enum "Normalize not required";
    }
    when "../../enable-L3-access = 'false' and ../traffic-type = 'Transport single vlan' and ../traffic-types = 'Transport single vlan'";
  }
```

Comment: What you are asking is unclear. You should edit your question and improve it, if you want it to be answered.

Comment: Any XPath expression (which is what a when statement argument is) may be placed within parentheses in order to ensure operator priority. For example: `(expr1 and (expr2 or expr3))`. Square brackets are reserved for predicates, which further filter current selection. See [XPath 1.0 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Expressions).